# Automatically loads a php file that is a url of jquery Ajax method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, forms

I am using jquery ajax method to display a set of option values to a dropdown menu using my `title.php` file. But after loading the whole page, in chrome android browser it redirects to the `title.php`. Does anyone know what is the issue behind it?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'Title.php',
        success: function(e) {
            $(".name").html(e);
        }
    });
});
```

I don't have issue in my PC (win10 chrome browser). I have experienced this issue in android chrome browser.
 https://ibb.co/hggLr8

Here is the screenshot of the error I am having. One more thing I noted is that this issue is not appearing while I am using incognito tab.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it to

```
$(document).ready(funtion(){})
```

to

```
$(".name").change(funtion(){

//ajax code goes here

});
```

here (.name) is your select class="name"

hope this will help!

Comment: That is a datalist and I need to load all data values after loading the DOM. So that I used the $(document).ready() function.